# Como inserir valores dentro de uma chave usando List e JSON

Tags: c#, .net, json, winforms

Estou tentando fazer algo que me dê como saída isso:

```
[
    {
        "Nome": "João",
        "Comprou": [
                       "Carro": "Sedan", "Preco": "12000",
                       "Moto": "Honda", "Preco": "8000"
                   ]
    }
]
```

Para isso uso List e para salvar uso JSON.net. O problema é que não estou conseguindo colocar uma chave dentro de outra. Tentei dessa forma:

```
public class Cliente
{
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string[] Comprou { get; set; }
}
public static List<Cliente> Clientes = new List<Cliente>();
```

Não sei como atribuir um valor dentro de outro. Quero pegar os produtos e colocá-los em uma listbox para o determinado cliente que for selecionado em outra listbox. Tentei usando foreach:

```
Cliente cliente = Clientes[listaClientes.SelectedIndex];
foreach (var produto in cliente.Comprou)
{
        listaProdutosComprados.Items.Add(produto);
}
```

Eu queria colocar os valores como "Nome" e "Preco" assim como fiz com o cliente para depois poder mostrar estes valores em uma label ou textbox. Estou desenvolvendo este projeto em C# com uma aplicação WinForms.

Comment: Ola! Bem vindo ao SOPT. Que biblioteca esta a usar para serializar/desserializar?

Comment: @Omni Olá! Obrigado por se interessar em me ajudar a resolver o meu problema. Estou usando JSON.net

Answer (score 3):

Você precisa expandir um pouco mais seu modelo pro JSON.Net fazer a interpretação correta:

```
public class Cliente
{
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public List<Veiculo> Comprou { get; set; }
}

public class Veiculo
{
    public string Carro { get; set; }  
    public string Moto { get; set; }
    public Decimal Preco { get; set; }
}
```

Você pode instanciar assim:

```
var clientes = new List<Cliente> {
    Nome = "João", 
    Comprou = new List<Veiculo> {
        new Veiculo {
            Carro = "Sedan",
            Preco = 12000
        },
        new Veiculo {
            Moto = "Honda",
            Preco = 8000
        }
    }
};
```

Para serializar em JSON:

```
string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(clientes);
```

Fonte: http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html

Comment: Obrigado pela sua resposta! O problema é que o meu sistema funciona assim: eu cadastro um cliente e ele é adicionado em uma listbox feita para os clientes.
Quando eu seleciono um cliente na listbox posso cadastrar um produto para ele através da minha outra listbox para os produtos. O que eu preciso é que quando cadastrar o produto, o nome do produto que consta em uma textbox vá para a string "Nome" e o valor do produto que consta em outra textbox vá para o "Preco" do respectivo cliente selecionado.

Comment: Então você tem que montar as classes conforme coloquei ali na resposta no seu Code Behind. Isso não vem pronto do ASPX.

Comment: Eu precisaria relacionar uma classe com outra para depois fazer algo como `textbox1.Text = cliente.Comprou.Veiculo.Nome`
O nome do veículo no caso seria o que estiver selecionado na lista dos produtos. Por isso o `Cliente cliente = Clientes[listaClientes.SelectedIndex];`
Infelizmente não estou sabendo como fazer isso. Estou tentando o dia todo.

Comment: Bom, aí a dúvida não é mais sobre JSON, e sim sobre como você faz pra relacionar uma informação com a outra. Seria mais algo a ver com o Web Forms + JavaScript.

Comment: O JSON eu uso para salvar os dados e posteriormente carregá-los ao iniciar o programa.
Por exemplo, ao iniciar o arquivo é deserializado. O nome do cliente é adicionado na listbox dos clientes assim como é adicionado na Lista Cliente com suas demais informações.
O mesmo acontece com os produtos. O que preciso é relacionar um produto com o cliente. Estou desenvolvendo isso em C# numa aplicação Winforms.

Comment: segundo você comentou logo acima, o trecho de código `cliente.Comprou.Veiculo.Nome` não deve funcionar porque a propriedade `comprou`é uma lista ou um vetor. o certo seria `cliente.Comprou[0].Veiculo.Nome` ou algo parecido. E pela sua dúvida, acho que ou ela está mal formulado ou a sua lógica está com alguns problemas.

Comment: @RichardDias Eu acho meio difícil de explicar. Eu preciso cadastrar o produto que está selecionado em uma listbox para o cliente que está selecionado em outra listbox. O nome do produto, assim como o valor, eu pego pelo texto de uma textbox e atribuo ao `cliente.Comprou[listaClientes.SelectedIndex].Veiculo.Nome = caixaNomeVeiculo.Text` e ao `cliente.Comprou[listaClientes.SelectedIndex].Veiculo.Preco = caixaPrecoVeiculo.Text`

Comment: Mas pela sua lógica, o comentário acima está incorreto. deveria ser `cliente.Comprou[listaProdutos.SelectedIndex].Veiculo.Nome = caixaNomeVeiculo.Text`. De qualquer forma, acho que seria bom vc colocar dúvida de uma forma visual em papel, longe na IDE para montar uma lógica. Você falou que está usando windows forms, você está fazendo toda essa operação dentro de um componente `webBrowser`? Isso é realmente necessário?

Comment: @RichardDias a listbox tem que ser a do cliente porque o produto deve ser adicionado para ele. Eu estou desenvolvendo isso numa aplicação winforms no Visual C#.